# C: fwrite() vs (f)printf?

Tags: c, printf, fwrite

I was reading the manual page for the `getline` function and saw a demonstration of it :

```
 #define _GNU_SOURCE
       #include <stdio.h>
       #include <stdlib.h>

       int
       main(int argc, char *argv[])
       {
           FILE *stream;
           char *line = NULL;
           size_t len = 0;
           ssize_t nread;

        ...
           while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, stream)) != -1) {
               printf("Retrieved line of length %zu:\n", nread);
               fwrite(line, nread, 1, stdout); /* ? */
           }

           free(line);
           fclose(stream);
           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
       }
```

I replaced the `fwrite()` statement with `printf ("%s", line)` and it produced
identical results (compared using `cmp` and `diff`). I am aware of the distinction  between `fwrite` and `fprint` but was there any specifc reason the author chose to use `fwrite()` over `fprintf` or `printf` in this context ?

Comment: One writes formatted data, one writes memory content. Usage of *either* is entirely situational (just like everything else in the standard library; know what it does before you use it).

Comment: If you use `printf`, what happens when the input data contains any null bytes?

Comment: btw, why'd you delete your [latest question about fgetc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65751836/c-int-or-char-when-reading-from-a-file-byte-by-byte?noredirect=1), it was rather good duplicate signpost as it was...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference between `fwrite(line, nread, 1, stdout)` and `printf ("%s", line)` includes:

`printf ("%s", line)` writes up to the 1st null character.

`fwrite(line, nread, 1, stdout)` writes to length of input.

This differs when a *null character* was read and so using `fwrite()` provides correct functionality in that pathological case.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I disagree.  Please provide info that indicates `getline()` treats reading a _null character_ different that other characters.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch In fact, i see "On success, getline() and getdelim() return the number of
       characters read, including the delimiter character, but not
       including the terminating null byte ('\0').  This value can be
       used to handle embedded null bytes in the line read."

Answer (score 1):

> but was there any specific reason the author chose to use fwrite() over fprintf or printf in this context ?

Study the implementation of `fwrite` and `fprintf` inside [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/).

You'll find out that `fprintf` is more complex and more brittle, so slower, than `fwrite` is. It is also a lot harder to understand.

AFAIK, some compilers (including *sometimes* [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)) are able to [optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (in *simple* cases) some call to `fprintf` into something similar to your `fwrite`. You might try compiling your `foo.c` source code as `gcc -Wall -O3 -fverbose-asm -S foo.c` and look into the generated assembler code `foo.s`

Comment: If I follow correctly, the difference comes down to the cost of interpreting format strings, and the cost of replacing format specifiers with the correct values. In this case, the cost of `fwrite` would be closer to the cost of copying some data between buffers, and a possible `fflush` syscall.

Comment: The most important different is readability of C source code

Comment: Readability in this case is not a differentiator. Either version is simple enough to be understandable as an example.

Comment: you can disable this optimization by -fno-builtin-fprintf or -fno-builtin